# SDN 4 Neo4j own primary key and id() function

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j-4

I have added `uuid` property to my SDN 4 Base entity so now it looks like:

```
@NodeEntity
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Index(unique = true, primary = true)
    private Long uuid;

...
}
```

Right now when I'll use Neo4j Cypher `id()` function, what value will be taken into account by this `id(baseEntity)` function - from `Long id` or `Long uuid` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cypher's id() function always uses the internal id (what's annotated as the @GraphId) and not any custom id.